# Set background color in BarLegend

Tags: legending

I have a complex `Graphics3D` and would like to include a `BarLegend`, such as:

```
mylegend =
 BarLegend[{Hue[#] &, {0, 1}},
 LegendFunction -> "Frame",
 LegendLabel -> Text[Style["time (s)", 16]]]
```

I then `Insert` and place it into the full figure this way:

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[],
   Inset[barLegend, {1, 1, 1}]}]]
```

[image]

This is almost what I seek.  I would like mylegend to have a solid background color to thus obscure the 3D graphics behind it, including the frame.

I could use `Placed` and `Framed` and `Background` and work hard to achieve this.  It would be so much simpler if a framed legend had the option of a background color, but as far as I can see from the documentation, it doesn't.  Obvious attempts such as to following do not work:

```
BackgroundColor -> Yellow

Background -> Yellow

Style -> {Black, Background -> Yellow}
```

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
barlegend =
  BarLegend[{Hue[#] &, {0, 1}},
    LegendFunction -> (Panel[#, Background -> Yellow] &),
    LegendLabel -> Text[Style["time (s)", 16]]]

Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Inset[barlegend, {1, 1, 1}]}]
```

[image: graphics]

#### Update

The following will force the legend to be drawn after the graphics box, but only allows positioning in the 2D coordinate of the graphics viewport.

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[],
  Epilog -> Inset[barlegend, Scaled[{.8, .6}]]]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: Very very curious.  Indeed, the yellow background obscures the sphere (thanks), but look carefully:  The "back" of the frame is visible through the legend!  What is going on?!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. That is because the frame is drawn after the legend.

Comment: So is there any way to "occlude" the frame by the legend?

Comment: m_goldberg:  *Hooray*... Thanks very much.  That works.

Answer (score 2):

In general you could do something like

```
{BarLegend["Rainbow", LabelStyle -> {Background -> LightBlue}],
 BarLegend["Rainbow", LabelStyle -> {Background -> LightBlue}], 
LegendFunction -> "Frame"}
```

[image]

But then you have little control of finer details, like that white gap between background and frame. So to help you with "hard work", I just adopt relevant example listed in docs page for the function [BarLegend](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html). That example in docs is basically telling you "this is how you currently suppose to do it".

```
frame[legend_] := Framed[legend, FrameStyle -> Red, 
RoundingRadius -> 10, FrameMargins -> 10, Background -> LightGreen]

mylegend = BarLegend[{Hue[#] &, {0, 1}}, 
LegendFunction -> frame, LegendLabel -> Text[Style["time (s)", 16]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Inset[mylegend, {1, 1, 1}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy, but when I `Insert` your barlegend into a Graphics3D figure, for some reason it remains transparent and you can see the 3D figure (such as the frame) "through" it, as you can see from your figure.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it works for me on mac in 11.1 as you can see from image i added to my reply. You are probably on WIN. This is probably related to an issue that is currently is being fixed and in future it will work.

Comment: I'm using v. 10.4 on a Mac.  Regardless, on this website your bar legend does *not* obscure or occlude the frame as I hope to achieve.